# asp.net C# DateTime Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datetime, conditional-statements

I have a Listview which fetches data from a SQL Database. One of the columns is a date which takes data from the database in the format "mm/dd/yyyy 0:00:00 AM"

I'm trying to get the date to highlight if its over an hour old from DateTime.Now

Here is what I have now (yes I know it's wrong)

```
Label TimeLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TPTIMEIN");
            if (TimeLabel != null)
            {
                DateTime Total;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(TimeLabel.Text, out Total) == true)
                {
                    if (Total < (DateTime.Now))
                    {
                        TimeLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        TimeLabel.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help will be really appreciated, I'm quite new to coding so go easy on me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.AddHours(1)`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
if(Total > DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)) 
{
     TimeLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     TimeLabel.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be something as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
String dtFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";

String dtString = "02/01/2015 10:01:56 AM";


DateTime dtObject = DateTime.ParseExact(dtString, dtFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (dtObject.AddHours(1) >= DateTime.Now)
{
    //Greater
}
else
{
    // Smaller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(Total).TotalHours > 1)
{
    //Change the label color here
}
```